# How can I write JSDoc comment for class with dynamic constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

```
class SampleClass {
  /**
   * @param {ClassHasGetNameMethod[]} array
   */
  constructor (array) {
    array.forEach((v) => {
      this[v.getName()] = v
    })
  }

  methodInSampleClass () {
    // something
  }
}

const arr = [value0, value1, ...] // ex: valueN.getName() : unkonwn string
const sampleVar = new SampleClass(arr)
```

`sampleVar` is similar to `@type { Object.<string, ClassHasGetNameMethod> }` but this type is `SampleClass`.

I want to use intelisense on VSCoode but `sampleVar.name0` is recognized as `any`.

If I know the names or length of argument, I can write `/** @type {ClassHasGetNameMethod} */`.

When the argument is dynamic as described above, how do I write JSDoc comment to `SampleClass`?

Comment: You'd need to make `SampleClass` a generic over the type that `ClassHasGetNameMethod.getName` returns

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I searched many pages about generic in JSDoc but I can't   found...
Could you show me sample JSDoc documentation?

Comment: I don't know JSDoc, but generics in TypeScript are documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)